# How set the back button on the left in ionic

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic in my project. How can I set the back button on the left in the header? Here is my code:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="left" >
<h1 class="title" style="text-align: center">More Info</h1>

<button  ng-click="myGoBack()" class="button  button-clear"> <i class="ion- chevron-left " ></i> Back </button>

</ion-header-bar>

  <ion-view>
 <ion-content >
<ion-list class="list-inset" style="margin-right: 1%;margin-right: 1%">
  <ion-item style="margin-right: 1%;margin-right: 1%" class="item-text-wrap" ng-init="missionDetail.getAllFicheMissionDetails(missionId,desId);">
    vehicule :{{payloadMissionDetail.vehicule}}
    Mission :{{payloadMissionDetail.mission}}
    Chau1 :{{payloadMissionDetail.ch}}
    Chau2 :{{payloadMissionDetail.ch2}}
    Départ :{{payloadMissionDetail.depart}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: is this your whole code for menu template ? Provide us the full code

Comment: yes..this is just a page ..this code set the back button on the right..but i want to change it on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
<button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
 </div>
 <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
 <div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">Right Button</button>
 </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

@Documentation : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/